# Polynomial ring of invariants and graphs

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, symmetric-polynomials, invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a finite simple graph with nodes enumerated as $1, 2, ..., n$. Assign a variable $x_i$ to node number $i$. Consider the action of $\mathrm{Aut}\, G \subset S_n$ on the polynomial ring
$$\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n],$$
where element $g \in \mathrm{Aut}\, G$ permutes variables just as it permutes nodes.
By classical invariant theory the ring of invariants
$$\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n]^{\mathrm{Aut}\, G}$$
is finitely generated over $\mathbb{C}$.

**Question:** What is an upper bound $B$ on degrees of generators of $\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n]^{\mathrm{Aut}\, G}$ in terms of $n$?

For example, if we consider graphs with $n=3$ vertices, we can enumerate all possible cases and the upper bound will turn out to be $B = 3$. If the graph is $K_3$ or has no edges, then $\mathrm{Aut}\, G = S_3$ and hence the ring of invariants is given by
$$\mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, x_3]^{S_3} = \mathbb{C}[\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3].$$
If the graph has 1 or 2 edges, then $\mathrm{Aut}\, G = S_2$ and the ring of invariants is generated by polynomials of degree $\leq 2$.

**Addendum:** Note that for arbitrary subgroup of $S_n$ the upper bound is known to be $n(n-1)/2$. Hence the graph structure plays a crucial role in restricting which subgroups $\mathrm{Aut}\, G \subset S_n$ can appear.